# Search for emails sent to a person containing a keyword in iOS Outlook?

Tags: outlook

On my iPhone, using Outlook, can I search for a keyword in a mail received from somebody? If I search for the keyword I see all the emails I received from everybody containing the keyword. But is there a way to search for all the emails sent to a particular user containing the keyword?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Search for the name - this should bring it up at the top of the page - select it and recent emails should be shown. If that doesn't work, try searching for "keyword name".